# How to resize the legend label in Matplotlib Graph

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

[image: Population Distribution Graph]

I wish to resize the Population label seen in the legend, I want the circle to be smaller than it is right now. How do I do that ?

Comment: Please note that just screenshots of code are not allowed here. Also [edit] your question with the code as text please, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but the easiest is to set the desired size in the legend. That size will be a manual setting.

```
plt.legend(markerscale=0.5)
```

[image]